# Background-clip text mouse tracking animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to track user's mouse and display a gradient text using `background-clip: text;`

The text should always be visible with a color of black. Only when hovering the text, the gradient should show up (inside of text) and move together with mouse movement.

Is something like this possible?

I found this [tutorial](https://bholmes.dev/blog/a-shiny-on-hover-effect-that-follows-your-mouse-css/) where they're animating the background. However when I am trying to add `background-clip: text;` it doesn't work anymore.

Here is what I got:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".shiny");

button.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const { x, y } = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  button.style.setProperty("--x", e.clientX - x);
  button.style.setProperty("--y", e.clientY - y);
});
```

```css
.shiny {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #3984ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 33px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shiny::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--y, 0) * 1px - 50px);
  left: calc(var(--x, 0) * 1px - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.shiny:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: radial-gradient(black, red 80%);
 
  *-webkit-background-clip: text;
    *background-clip: text;
    *-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a class="shiny" href="">BIG AND BOLD TEXT</a>
```

Comment: it's not clear to me visually what you're looking for. example drawings would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a pseudo element but multiple background layer:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".shiny");

button.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const { x, y } = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  button.style.setProperty("--x", (e.clientX - x)+"px");
  button.style.setProperty("--y", (e.clientY - y)+"px");
});
```

```css
.shiny {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(50px at var(--x,0) var(--y,0),red,#000),
    #3984ff;
  -webkit-background-clip: text,padding-box;
          background-clip: text,padding-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 33px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .3s;
}
.shiny:hover {
 color:#0000;
}
```

```html
<a class="shiny" href="">BIG AND BOLD TEXT</a>
```